# Can I pass more arguments into event handler functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have been trying to find out more about mouse events such as `onmouseover`, `onmouseout` and `onmousemove` but there is not much info. It seems these event handlers by default have a single argument, the event its self.

```
element.onmouseover = mouseoverFunction

function mouseoverFunction( event ) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

However I want to be able to pass other arguments to into the function.

```
function mouseoverFunction( event, moreArgs ) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

How do I pass the event argument and additional arguments to the function?

Also is it ok to pass more arguments into an event handler function?

Answer (score 6):

You can make a higher-order function:

```
function mouseover(arg1, arg2) {
  return function(event) {
    // Do stuff here
  }
}

element.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseover(1, 2))
```

Comment: I did look at that but saw it was not supported by IE8 and under

Comment: Look for an `addEventListener` polyfill, or use the `onmouseover` attribute as you were doing.

Comment: @elclanrs, I was looking forward to call & apply methods. Is this possible to do that using them. I couldn't pass in event into the function if I pass in other arguments