# How can I pass other arguments to event handler in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to pass both the event and some other data (the index of an element) to an event handler in a React App. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054692/can-i-pass-more-arguments-into-event-handler-functions-in-javascript) that I should make a `higher-order` function, but I don't get a pleasant result. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
  const changeNameHandler = (index) => {
    return (event) => {
      console.log(index, event);
    };
  };

  let persons = null;

  if(showValuesState) {
    persons = (
      <div>
        {
          personsState.map((person, index) => {
            return <Person
              name = {person.name}
              age = {person.age}
              click = {() => deletePersonHandler(index)}
              key = {index}
              changeName = {() => changeNameHandler(index)()}/>
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I am trying to *pass the index* to `changeNameHandler` function while also getting the event, but the *value of* the **event variable** from that `console.log(index, event)` statement is still `undefined`.

Comment: ```changeName = {(event) => changeNameHandler(event, index)}/>```

Comment: Please don't include answers in the question; self-answering is fine. This is likely a dupe though, like https://stackoverflow.com/q/51042381/438992 etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when ever you are calling a function from inside your jsx, if you wanted to pass extra values rather that the event, you have to consider doing like below:

```
changeName = {() => changeNameHandler(index)}/>
```

Also the important point is that you are getting the function hooked up on the `changeName` prop of your `Person` component but you don't capture the `event` value from it, so if you need to access the event value inside of your handler  you have to do it like below:

```
changeName = {(evt) => changeNameHandler(evt, index)}/>
```

and by doing this you will get the event as first argument and he index value as second argument in your handler.

```
const changeNameHandler = (evt, index) => {
  // do what ever you want here with values 
}
```